# When can I omit ‘from’ in ‘from~to~’?

Tags: sentence-construction

1. I write A to Z alphabets
2. I write from A to Z alphabets
3. I write alphabets A to Z
4. I write alphabets from A to Z

Are all of these sentences acceptable? I think only sentence 4 is correct one.

Comment: A and Z are ***letters***, not "alphabets". All the letters of a language combined are called "an alphabet", or "the alphabet" if it's clear which language you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

All of these sentences sound strange without more context.

> I write alphabets

What does this mean?  It's a hobby?  You take different languages (English, French, German, Greek, Hebrew, Russian) and write out the alphabet of each one?  "From A to Z" doesn't make sense in that case, because many alphabets don't use A or Z as letters.

If you just mean the English alphabet, then what you may intend is:

> I write the alphabet from A to Z.

It's **the** alphabet, not because there's only one alphabet in the world, but because it implies **the alphabet of the language you're speaking.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the word "letter" not "alphabet".  The use of the the word "alphabet" to mean individual letters is common in some Indian dialects of English, but is a mistake in British and American English.

With that the best sentence would be

> I write letters from A to Z.

Though you could omit "from", especially in casual contexts.

It would be even better to say "I write the alphabet".  Because "the alphabet is the list of letters from A-Z!" You don't need to say "from A to Z" because "the alphabet" means "from A to Z".